# Send default argument value to a function?

Tags: swift, default-arguments

TL;DR

If I have `func show(message: String = "Hello")`, how can I send it the default argument **without omitting the parameter name**? (E.g. `show(message: default)`)

Note: `show()` is not what I'm looking for! See below for details why.

---

Imagine we have the following function defined:

```
func makeCreature(color: UIColor, eyeCount: Int = 2, noseCount: Int = 1) -> Creature {
  // ...
}
```

Then we also have another method defined, `makeCreatures`:

```
func makeCreatures(count: Int, color: UIColor) {
  for 1...count {
    makeCreature(color: color)
  }
}
```

However, now we want to easily customize the eyeCount and noseCount for `makeCreatures`. One way to do that is to redefine the arguments and their default values:

**Solution #1**

```
func makeCreatures(count: Int, color: UIColor, eyeCount: Int = 2, noseCount: Int = 1) {
  for 1...count {
    makeCreature(color: color, eyeCount: eyeCount, noseCount: noseCount)
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that if the default amount of eyes ever changes, I need to remember to update it in 2 places: `makeCreature` and `makeCreatures`.

What I would hope to do instead is define the method as:

```
func makeCreatures(count: Int, color: UIColor, eyeCount: Int? = nil, noseCount: Int? = nil)
```

However, this now means I have to create 4 different `if` branches:

**Solution #2**

```
func makeCreatures(count: Int, color: UIColor, eyeCount: Int? = nil, noseCount: Int? = nil) {
  for 1...count {
    if let eyeCount = eyeCount, let noseCount = noseCount {
      makeCreature(color: color, eyeCount: eyeCount, noseCount: noseCount) 
    } else if let eyeCount = eyeCount {
      makeCreature(color: color, eyeCount: eyeCount)
    } else if let noseCount = noseCount {
      makeCreature(color: color, noseCount: noseCount)
    } else {
      makeCreature(color: color)
    }
  }
}
```

Having to create 4 different branches is a bit ugly and hard to understand. Is there a better way that gives me the conciseness of solution #1 with the DRYness of #2? Something similar to this:

**Ideal Solution?**

```
func makeCreatures(count: Int, color: UIColor, eyeCount: Int? = nil, noseCount: Int? = nil) {
  for 1...count {
    makeCreature(color: color, 
      eyeCount: eyeCount ?? default, 
      noseCount: noseCount ?? default)
  }
}
```

Where `default` means use the default argument value as defined in `makeCreature` (i.e. `2` for `eyeCount` and `1` for `noseCount`).

If not, what are the other solutions that can help me achieve this goal?

Comment: Just set two Int constants in some scope available to both functions, and make them the default arguments of the functions.  No need for optionals either.

Comment: I'm curious as to why your `makeCreature` isn't an initializer on `Creature`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but you can use the builder pattern for this:

```
struct Creature {
    let color: UIColor
    let eyeCount: Int
    let noseCount: Int
}

struct CreatureBuilder {
    var color: UIColor?
    var eyeCount: Int = 2 //store defaults here
    var noseCount: Int = 1

    func build() -> Creature {
        guard let color = color else { fatalError("Creatures need a color!") }

        return Creature(color: color, eyeCount: eyeCount, noseCount: noseCount)
    }
}

func makeCreatures(count: Int, color: UIColor, eyeCount: Int? = nil, noseCount: Int? = nil) {
    var builder = CreatureBuilder()
    builder.color = color;
    if let eyeCount = eyeCount { builder.eyeCount = eyeCount } //override defaults only for non-nil params
    if let noseCount = noseCount { builder.noseCount = noseCount }

    for _ in 1...count {
        let creature = builder.build() //TODO: do something with the creature.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, there's another solution similar to [Alexander's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander-momchliov).

You can create a struct to hold on to the attributes of a creature:

```
struct Attributes {
  let color: UIColor
  let eyeCount: Int = 2
  let noseCount: Int = 1
}
```

Then redefine the functions to take in the attributes:

```
func makeCreature(attributes: Attributes) -> Creature {
  // ...
}

func makeCreatures(count: Int, attributes: Attributes) {
  for 1...count {
    makeCreature(color: color, attributes: attributes)
  }
}
```

Which allows you to use default values with both functions:

```
// uses 2 eyes (default), and 2 noses
makeCreature(attributes: Attributes(color: .purple, noseCount: 2))

// use 10 eyes, and 1 nose (default)
makeCreatures(count: 3, attributes: Attributes(color: .blue, eyeCount: 10))
```